# Marionette attributes is not defined, get from API

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm studying Marionette Gentle Introduction, facing some issues with the Single Contact API part.

Ok let's get straight to the point.

this is my template

```
        <script type="text/template" id="contact-view">
            <%= id %>
            <h1><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %></h1>
            <p><strong>Phone number:</strong> <%= phoneNumber %></p>
        </script>
```

this is part of my controller

```
   showContact: function(id){
        var contact = ContactManager.request('contact:model', id);
        var contactView;
        if(contact !== undefined)
        {
            contactView = new Show.Contact({
                model: contact
            });
        }
        else
        {
            contactView = new Show.MissingContact();
        }

        ContactManager.mainRegion.show(contactView);
    }
```

this is part of my model

```
Entities.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "php/contacts/index.php",
    defaults: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phoneNumber: ''
    }
});

var API = {
    getContactEntity: function(contactId){
        var contact = new Entities.Contact({id:contactId});
        contact.fetch();

        return contact;
    }
};

ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("contact:model", function(id){
    return API.getContactEntity(id);
});
```

and this is my php API

```
$data[] = array('id'=>1, 'firstName'=>'Alice', 'lastName'=>'Arten', 'phoneNumber'=>'555-0184');
$data[] = array('id'=>2, 'firstName'=>'Bob', 'lastName'=>'Brigham', 'phoneNumber'=>'555-0184');
$data[] = array('id'=>3, 'firstName'=>'Charlie', 'lastName'=>'Campbell', 'phoneNumber'=>'555-0184');
echo json_encode($data[1]);
```

I tried to keep it simple. So the error is the following when i remove the defaults

```
firstName is not defined
```

And i tried to console log the contact in the model, please refer to this http://prntscr.com/51k7ec

I'm pretty sure that it is getting the attribute from the previousAttributes instead of the attributes

Please help me out. Did i do anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could u please attach code of `reqres.setHandler("contact:model" ...)`

Comment: already attached in the model part. thanks

Comment: I see, fetch is async, of u fave to wait till it will be finished

Comment: sorry, i don't get what you mean.

Comment: can you show the view's code?

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself. Are you by chance using a backend rather than the web storage the tutorial suggests? I have been banging my head against this for a day now. I've tried the promise/deferred route as well, and still see the same results. It's like the object being returned from the .fetch() is not actually a model at all. Oddly, the collection .fetch() works fine. were you able to fix this?

Comment: I just noticed you showed some of your PHP server code. So you are using a backend. Thanks.

Comment: Just to help anyone who might be looking into this same issue - I found that my server was returning an array with one item in it, while the backbone .fetch() was expecting a single item. The fact that backbone didn't error on this blows my mind, as every other framework I've used does. But, there it is. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) method of `Backbone.Model` returns [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. `fetch` method asynchronous by default so you need to attach callback to [promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) returned from it, and then in that callback you will have access to actual fetched model.

I will suggest you to read more about [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object to understand it more deeply.

For your issue I will suggest you to attach promise object to your model:

```
var API = {
    getContactEntity: function(contactId){
        var contact = new Entities.Contact({id:contactId});
        contact.promise = contact.fetch();
        return contact;
    }
};
```

And then in your controller file wrap rendering part with done callback :

```
showContact: function(id){
    var contact = ContactManager.request('contact:model', id);
    var contactView;
    contact.promise.done(function (){
    if(contact !== undefined)
    {
        contactView = new Show.Contact({
            model: contact
        });
    }
    else
    {
        contactView = new Show.MissingContact();
    }

    ContactManager.mainRegion.show(contactView);

    });
}
```

In this case some part of your code will work. Why some part? Cause `else` block will never execute. 
Your `if` statement is incorrect. Your model cannot be `undefined`. It can raise an error and stop execution of your code but it cannot be `undefined`. In case of error you could attach `fail` callback to your promise and handle that case.

If you showing contact and sure that `id` exists in your backend just remove the `if` statement and add `fail` callback with `else` case, be sure to make changes in backend API to respond with `404 Not found` when id doesn't exists.